# Implicit formula for the Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, connections, lie-derivative

Let  $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $X, Y, Z$ smooth vector fields on $M$. Let $\theta_X$ be the $1$-form defined as $\theta_X(Y) = g(X,Y)$ and let $d\theta_X$ be its exterior derivative. Let $L_X$ denote the Lie derivative. Let $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection, i.e. the unique torsion free connection on $(M,g)$ which is also compatible with the metric. I want to prove that: 
$$
2 g(\nabla_Y X, Z) = (L_Xg)(Y,Z) + (d \theta_X)(Y,Z).
$$
Is there a quick way to see that?

EDIT: I'm stuck with the $2$-form $d\theta_X$. I don't know how to deal with it. Can I express it just using the metric and the Lie derivative (without working in local coordinates)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most succinct proof of the uniqueness and existence of the Levi-Civita connection.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140884/most-succinct-proof-of-the-uniqueness-and-existence-of-the-levi-civita-connectio)

Comment: See the [relevant paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection#Formal_definition) from the Wikipedia article on the Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my problem is to deal with $d\theta_X$. I edited my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [invariant formula for the exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_invariant_formula), we have that

$$\textrm d \theta_X (Y, Z) = Y \cdot \theta_X (Z) - Z \cdot \theta_X (Y) - \theta_X ([Y, Z]) = Y \cdot g(X, Z) - Z \cdot g(X, Y) - g(X, [Y, Z]) .$$

Similarly, using the [properties of the Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#Lie_derivative_of_tensor_fields), we have

$$(L_X g) (Y, Z) = X \cdot g(Y, Z) - g([X, Y], Z) - g(Y, [X, Z]) .$$

Putting all these together we obtain

$$(L_X g) (Y, Z) + \textrm d \theta_X (Y, Z) = X \cdot g(Y, Z) + Y \cdot g(Z, X) - Z \cdot g(X, Y) - g([X, Y], Z) - g([Y, Z], X) - g([X, Z], Y) .$$

This last expression [is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140884/most-succinct-proof-of-the-uniqueness-and-existence-of-the-levi-civita-connectio) to be equal to $2 g (\nabla_Y X, Z)$ by [Koszul's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection#Formal_definition) (warning: the link to Wikipedia points to formulae that obtain $\nabla_X Y$, not $\nabla_Y X$, so a sign will differ!).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but differential forms are a very new thing to me. ;)